# Does Azure Sql Database Premium Edition allow for more than 150GB Databases?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I haven't been able to find an answer in the docs:

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/details/sql-database/#service-premium

Comment: It looks like information about Premium is closely guarded behind a sales rep. The [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee336245.aspx) doesn't even acknowledge Premium exists. You'll probably have to contact their sales staff directly and ask.

Comment: Granted (as of today) SQL DB Premium is in preview (not GA)...This might be a slight tangent on your question, but I have been really disappointed with the performance of SQL Database Premium.  Both the P1 and P2 reservations seems to be slower in bursts than the regular SQL Azure DB.  Profiling my SQL Azure DB, I have gotten burts of up to 3.5 CPUs.  (this might be wrong) However, in SQL Azure DB Premium your DB is "deployed" to a dedicated VM with either 1 or 2 CPUs.  So, the cap on resources is lower...but performance is more predictable and enables more concurrent connections.

Comment: Bart, while you said you're capped, with the predictable performance, throttling is no longer a concern right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [whitepaper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn369873.aspx) describing the capabilities of the Premium Preview for Windows Azure SQL Database (Premium) indicates the limit to be 150GB for a single instance.

Comment: When I read it, I interpreted the sharding section as general guidance and wasn't 100% sure.  I'll leave this open a little longer or otherwise try to find the answer and close it.

Comment: A single database in SQL (Windows Azure SQL Database) cannot be larger than 150GB at the time being. Premium feature only offers better performance targets! Neil is absolutely right and you will not find anything else beyond that (unless something changes in the future).

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to contact the sales team for that. I've heard of cases where the customers where so big that special provisions were made for them on the backend.

Answer (score 0):

Premium, as released today, allows one to go up to 500GB.  It is an option in the Azure portal under DB "Scale", once you have setup a quota with MS to be allowed to use the new additions.